# How can I deploy my PHP application on Google cloud Platform?

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have previously developed 1 website using php and mysql now I want to deploy it on Google cloud platform.
It will be great if someone only point out steps for below points

1.install PHP 7.x

2.creating .YAML files

3.creating mysql databse

4.upload my PHP file

5.FTP setup

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow steps 
[here](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-lamp)

it will help you setup LAMP server and upload files to server using FTP 
(which you can connect using SMTP-keyfile method) and also this document help you to setup mySQL database

Answer (score 1):

1. You can start setting up you environment like the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/setting-up-environment) describes.
2. For creating ".YAML" files there is also [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/apis#configuration-files) by google.
3. To create your MySQL database you should check [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-instance#create-2nd-gen) about creating Cloud SQL.
4. To upload PHP file you can use follow the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) and learn more about Cloud Storage and how to upload objects.
5. About ftp setup, can you specify why you trying to achieve using it? If you want to transfer files you can you see again the documentation of 4.

Comment: I've created .YAML file and also created MySQL databse and uploaded all PHP files to bucket as shown in step 4. now how can I create URL that call the Index.php ?

Comment: The command you are searching for is described in the documentation [1] 
gsutil cp gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME] [OBJECT_DESTINATION]
[1]: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects

Comment: NO, currently I've uploaded all file on google cloud storage and created database but how can I access my website?

Comment: Hi, uploading application files in Cloud Storage is an option but only for static files. If you deploy your app in App Engine you don't necessarily need to upload all your application files to Cloud Storage because App Engine will put your static files in a managed static files server. You only need to set this in the app.yaml file. I'll put the instructions in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a large set of example applications for deploying to App Engine [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/6ccd02e6ee54d897ca643ec46771c799c7db7c37/appengine/php72), or on [cloud.google.com](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/tutorials).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Google App Engine - this is the easiest way to deploy app withount install LAMP and FTP. Withount MySQL its free! See the quickstart: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/quickstart

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question in the comment;

> I've created .YAML file and also created MySQL databse and uploaded
>   all PHP files to bucket as shown in step 4. now how can I create URL
>   that call the Index.php ?

If you deploy your app in App Engine you don't necessarily need to upload all your application files to Cloud Storage because App Engine will put your static files in a managed static files server. You only need to set this in the [app.yaml file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element).

I suggest you to take a look at the this [sample application](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/php72/cloudsql)'s files  , so you can have a good idea on how to set all configuration files in order to deploy your app to App Engine standard environment and connect to Cloud SQL.

App Engine will create a default URL for you app under appspot.com domain, check for details [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/an-overview-of-app-engine#application_requests).

For more information on how you can connect to Cloud SQL from GAE standard take a look [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/using-cloud-sql).